# Getting the row/column reduction matrix of a matrix m

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Is there a simple way to get the row reduction matrix for a matrix `m`? As in, a matrix `a` such that `a.m=m'` where `m'` is in row reduced form? For things like SmithDecomposition, part of the function gives the required basis transformation matrices, but there doesn't seem to be a built in function like this for normal row reduction.

Comment: Have you seen `LUDecomposition[]`?

Comment: Or try `RowReduce'

Comment: Entering `Row reduction` in the help browser gives a list of options to look at.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you might also want to look at `HermiteDecomposition[]`.